# What is X-Playback-Session-Id header in Safari HTML5 player?

Tags: safari, video-streaming, html5-video, avplayer, http-live-streaming

I found that the native Safari HTML5 Player(suppose it is AVPlayer under the hood), adds X-Playback-Session-Id header for each master/media playlists and chunks requests.

Unfortunately, I can't find any official documentation or spec on this topic.

I am just curious about what is this header about and how it is computed?

Because of the lack of documentation on this:

Is it a stable one?

Can We rely on this header in production?